# No Nicotine+ in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, 20.04

There seems to be no Nicotine+ version for Ubuntu 20.04. Is there anyone working on it or should I downgrade to 19.10 or 18.04?

Comment: It will be your decision. The software may not anymore be maintained by the developpers, hence might have been dropped by the Ubuntu devs if packaging for 20.04 has become difficult.

Comment: There is a [PPA unstable](https://launchpad.net/~nicotine-team/+archive/ubuntu/unstable), which includes 20.04. No stable version yet.

Answer (score 2):

It was removed because of Python 2 deprecation, but you can still install by downloading its packages from 19.10 manually

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe

mkdir -p ~/Downloads/nicotine
cd ~/Downloads/nicotine

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nicotine/nicotine_1.2.16+dfsg-1.1_all.deb

sudo apt install ./*.deb
```

and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, for some reason I didn't manage to install python-gtk2.

Answer (score 2):

I finally installed Soulseek appimage, which works fine in 20.04. But good to know that there is already [unstable](https://launchpad.net/~nicotine-team/+archive/ubuntu/unstable) version of Nicotine+, thanks, mikewhatever.